# Swift / Firebase Tableview cells not refreshing after child removed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I realize this is a bit of a mess but i'm learning how things work by piecing things together from tutorials and reference materials.
My issue is when I remove a node from firebase, the tableview doesnt update.  It's deleted from firebase but the cell remains in the tableview.  Although not shown below, i've tried adding the mytableview.reload block of code every where I thought it should go, but I've had no success.  Any input is appreciated.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return eventsList.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
    cell.locationLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].location
    cell.eventTimeLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].dateTime
    cell.eventTypeLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].agencyEventSubtypeCode
    cell.agencyIdLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].agencyId

    if eventsList[indexPath.row].alarmLevel == "1" {
        cell.locationLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        cell.eventTimeLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        cell.eventTypeLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        cell.agencyIdLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    }
    return cell
}



    ref = Database.database().reference()
    fetchData()
}

func fetchData(){
    refHandle = ref?.child("caddata").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {

            let event =  Events()
            event.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            if event.originatingAction == "CadEventNew" {
                   self.eventsList.append(event)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myTableView.reloadData()
                }

            } else if event.originatingAction == "CadCloseEvent" {
                self.cadPacketType = event.originatingAction
                self.cadEventNumber = event.agencyEventId
                self.queryCloseUIDFromDB()
            }
        }
    })
}

func queryCloseUIDFromDB(){

    if cadPacketType == "CadCloseEvent" {

        let dataRef = ref?.child("caddata")
        let queryRef = dataRef?.queryOrdered(byChild: "agencyEventId")
            .queryEqual(toValue: cadEventNumber)

        queryRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for snap in snapshot.children {
                let dataSnap = snap as! DataSnapshot
                self.closeUID = dataSnap.key //the uid of each event

                if self.closeUID != nil {
                    self.deleteFromDB()

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.myTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

func deleteFromDB () {
    if closeUID != nil {
        print (cadEventNumber!)
        print (closeUID!)
        ref?.child("caddata").child(closeUID!).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                self.fetchData()
                print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
                    }
                })
            }
        print ("\(String(describing: closeUID)) has been removed")
}
```

Comment: can you post your `UITableViewDataSource` methods?

Comment: in your `deleteFromDB` method you need to update your array and call to `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction on how to update the array?  I added tableview functions to the original post

Comment: call `fetchData` method if no error is present in your closure where you remove the value, let me know

Comment: I tried the fetchData idea and it didnt work. It reloads correctly when I return from a map segue, but not when fetchData is called in the if statement of deleteFromDB func

Comment: can you update your question with what you last code? @jvan

Comment: @ReinierMelian Updated

Comment: check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the data again after delete,

replace your `deleteFromDB` method by this one, your fetchData must be executed `if error == nil`

```
func deleteFromDB () {
    if closeUID != nil {
        print (cadEventNumber!)
        print (closeUID!)
        ref?.child("caddata").child(closeUID!).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            //clean the array
            self.eventsList.removeAll()
            self.fetchData()
        })
    }
    print ("\(String(describing: closeUID)) has been removed")
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work either.  By recalling fetchData, I end up just appending the same list over and over to my tableview and it still doesnt remove the cell with the data for the deleted node.

Comment: @jvan check my answer again, I think you need clean the array before calling fetchData method, let me know if finally works

Comment: That works for a short time then I get Fatal error: Index out of range.